# Effcient way to do scheduled background job in android

Tags: java, android

I need to fetch the device location and battery percentage for every 5 to 10 min .

I have tried some below mentioned methods such as

1. Alaram Manager
   It works fine in most of the devices  below the android 8.1 . In android 8.1 it works for few hours and the it stops working
2. Job scheduler & work manager

It works fine in most of device but they have restriction of minimum 15minutes. Also it not works in few mobiles(xiaomi,Oneplus...)
 after terminationg the app

Is there any better and effcient way to do scheduled background job for every 10 min

Note: [Also i didn't tried FCM because it may drain the battery percentage more compared to aboved listed way

Comment: Waking up the device every 5 to 10 minutes is prohibitively expensive no matter what technique you use - that's why the minimum time frame for JobScheduler/WorkManager is at minimum 15 minutes.

Comment: Accodring to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits.html), starting with Android O background apps receive location updates several times per hour. If you need to update location more often, create a foreground service.